# Cigarette smoke animation

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation, particles

I would like to do an animation of cigarette smoke, preferrably using UIKit (and not, say, Cocos). I have worked with CAEmitterLayer before and gotten good results for various smoke and fog effects. Problem is, cigarette smoke looks nothing like the smoke from a fire. Using particles, I usually get something like this:

[image]

But what I am after is more like this:

[image]

Perhaps using particles isn't the best approach here?

Comment: Fluid dynamics us what would do this job.

Comment: I think it is more like fluid than particulate.  Practically speaking, though, and sticking with UIKit, you might get an okay effect with a real good set of pngs set as UIImageView.animationImages.

Comment: You might try repeating your request on the [Signal Processing SO site](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/), or maybe the [Physics SO site](http://physics.stackexchange.com/).  May not get a "hit" but no real harm in trying.